# Avoid processing wheelEvent in foreground items

Tags: c++, qml, qt-quick, qt4.8

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB1CA.png

I have a QDeclarativeItem that processes wheelEvents, and a few Rectangles declared in QML laying on top of it.
Mouse-wheel scrolls are processed when the cursor is above those items, which is not needed. 
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to make a new QDeclarativeItem, catch wheelEvent inside with `event->accept()`, and wrap it around my rectangles in QML.
It'a a bit annoying to wrap all the rectangles (when there is a lot of them), but it looks like there is no other way to catch WheelEvents in QML code with Qt4.8.